# Calculate Tiles X,Y, Z for current view or extent in OpenLayers

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, tiles

Im using OpenLayers with the openstreetmap tile server.

```
var urlTemplate = "http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
```

I would like to download tiles for the current view or an extent. So that I can view them later offline.

**Therefore Im trying to calculate the z, x,y for the tiles**

The coordinate Z should be avaible from the maps zoom

**But how can I find the different x,y Coordinates for the view/extent?  Is there a OpenLayers funtion for that?**

Comment: Do you want to put in the visual view, or the geographic extent?

Comment: View would be good, but the extent is also ok. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, are you really on OpenLayers 2, or is an OpenLayers 3 solution also OK?

Comment: @BradHards oh that was I mistake! Of course its OpenLayers3! Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by Download? Where do you want to download the tiles to? I don't have a OL3 solution, but here is a Python script which does so. You can have a look at the code, and do the same. https://gist.github.com/devdattaT/dd218d1ecdf6100bcf15

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you and great job!